# add "mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so" module to "Apache 2.4.23 VC9" with python 2.7 installed for all users in windows 7

Tags: django, windows, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I have windows 7/64 bit and I have installed python 2.7 for all users and "Apache 2.4.23 VC9" from [here](http://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx?dli=QTr5kTSlXWz0ERN9CVzQ2SJVlUGRVYS52Yw40U) and "mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so" from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/modwsgi/mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so). and I have added this "mod_wsgi.so" module to modules folder in 
"C:\Apache24\modules".

But when I uncomment this line "LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so"
 in "C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf" I get an error when I run this command:

```
C:\Apache24\bin>httpd.exe
```

the error is :

"httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 181 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load
modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The specified module could not be found."

I checked like tens of different Apache versions and mod_wsgi.so versions and read lots of documentation, but none of them provide practical information and none of them seems to work!!!

Apache works fine without that line in its configuration file.

1. Is there anybody who can actually work with Apache and mod_wsgi.so
   in windows? If so can you provide the links you have used in here?
2. Are the links I am using to download correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: All the versions installed are 32 bit I think

Answer (score 0):

You are using Apache 2.4, but your mod_wsgi is compiled for Apache 2.2:  "mod_wsgi-win32-**ap22**py27-3.3.so". Look for a mod_wsgi with "ap24" in the name.

First install python 2.7 "for alle users", then get the correct mod_wsgi version. It did not load without python installed (for me).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Did you have success?

Comment: No, the error changed to "httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 129 of C:/Apache22/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load
C:/Apache22/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The specified module could not be found.". I have installed Apache 2.2.